# SpringBoot overwrites Content-Type charset encoding

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
Request Endpoint : 
POST /create.
Signature of create method in application layer:

(@RequestBody POJO body, @RequestHeader("x-xxxx-id") String xHeader)
```

**Problem**:

If I invoke the above API endpoint with a json body, header value with special characters like øæer
and using Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8. 
The header value that I receive in my application is: Ã¸Ã¦er (Inside the create method)

My spring application.properties content:

```
# enable http encoding support
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
# force the configured encoding
spring.http.encoding.force=true
```

With an interceptor I was able to see that the request headers were having a separate Content-Type:

```
{
Accept=[application/json, application/*+json],
**Content-Type=[text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1]**,
Content-Length=[2],
Accept-Charset=[big5, big5-hkscs, cesu-8, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai, ibm00858, ibm01140, ibm01141, ibm01142, ibm01143, ibm01144, ibm01145, ibm01146, ibm01147, ibm01148, ibm01149, ibm037, ibm1026, ibm1047, ibm273, ibm277, ibm278, ibm280, ibm284, ibm285, ibm290, ibm297, ibm420, ibm424, ibm437, ibm500, ibm775, ibm850, ibm852, ibm855, ibm857, ibm860, ibm861, ibm862, ibm863, ibm864, ibm865, ibm866, ibm868, ibm869, ibm870, ibm871, ibm918, iso-2022-cn, iso-2022-jp, iso-2022-jp-2, iso-2022-kr, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-13, iso-8859-15, iso-8859-2, iso-8859-3, iso-8859-4, iso-8859-5, iso-8859-6, iso-8859-7, iso-8859-8, iso-8859-9, jis_x0201, jis_x0212-1990, koi8-r, koi8-u, shift_jis, tis-620, us-ascii, utf-16, utf-16be, utf-16le, utf-32, utf-32be, utf-32le, utf-8, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252, windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, windows-31j, x-big5-hkscs-2001, x-big5-solaris, x-compound_text, x-euc-jp-linux, x-euc-tw, x-eucjp-open, x-ibm1006, x-ibm1025, x-ibm1046, x-ibm1097, x-ibm1098, x-ibm1112, x-ibm1122, x-ibm1123, x-ibm1124, x-ibm1166, x-ibm1364, x-ibm1381, x-ibm1383, x-ibm300, x-ibm33722, x-ibm737, x-ibm833, x-ibm834, x-ibm856, x-ibm874, x-ibm875, x-ibm921, x-ibm922, x-ibm930, x-ibm933, x-ibm935, x-ibm937, x-ibm939, x-ibm942, x-ibm942c, x-ibm943, x-ibm943c, x-ibm948, x-ibm949, x-ibm949c, x-ibm950, x-ibm964, x-ibm970, x-iscii91, x-iso-2022-cn-cns, x-iso-2022-cn-gb, x-iso-8859-11, x-jis0208, x-jisautodetect, x-johab, x-macarabic, x-maccentraleurope, x-maccroatian, x-maccyrillic, x-macdingbat, x-macgreek, x-machebrew, x-maciceland, x-macroman, x-macromania, x-macsymbol, x-macthai, x-macturkish, x-macukraine, x-ms932_0213, x-ms950-hkscs, x-ms950-hkscs-xp, x-mswin-936, x-pck, x-sjis_0213, x-utf-16le-bom, x-utf-32be-bom, x-utf-32le-bom, x-windows-50220, x-windows-50221, x-windows-874, x-windows-949, x-windows-950, x-windows-iso2022jp],
**X-XXXX-ID=[Ã¸Ã¦er]**,
X-FORWARDED-PROTO=[https], 
USER-AGENT=[PostmanRuntime/7.17.1], 
X-ORIGINAL-URI=[/create]}
```

In case of another endpoint which is GET /session
The same special character value for the same x-xxxx-id heder is passed and I receive proper value in the application as well.

```
{Accept=[application/json, application/*+json], 
Content-Length=[0], 
X-XXXX-ID=[øæer], 
USER-AGENT=[PostmanRuntime/7.17.1], 
X-ORIGINAL-URI=[/session]}
```

Comment: Why are you forcing utf8 encoding? From the properties definition : spring.http.encoding.force= # Whether to force the encoding to the configured charset on HTTP requests and responses.https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html Do you want to the client to set its custom encoding or not?

Comment: The problem here is that even if the client is sending the request with a Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, the request header value reaching the controller is converted to Content-Type=[text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1].

Comment: I thought it was exactly the opposite, that the client was sending with ISO-8859-1. Not sure then, you might want to transform to unicode those characters before sending..